# Missing 1 required positional argument: 'number'

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

Hi I'm having an issue running a asyncio loop it's asking for a `missing 1 required positional argument: 'number'.`

Here is what I'm working with:

```
async def purge_modlog(ctx, number):
    tomorrow = datetime.now()+timedelta(days=1)
    midnight = datetime(year=tomorrow.year, month=tomorrow.month, 
    day=tomorrow.day, hour=20, minute=35, second=0)
    number = int(number)
    server = before.server
    db = fileIO(self.direct, "load")
    if not server.id in db:
        return
    channel = db[server.id]["Channel"]
    if number > 99 or number < 1:
        await ctx.send("I can only delete messages within a range of 1 - 99", delete_after=10)
    else:
        author = ctx.message.author
        authorID = author.id
        mgs = []
        number = int(number)
        channel = modlog
        async for x in bot.logs_from((channel), limit = int(number+1)):
            mgs.append(x)
            await asyncio.sleep((midnight - datetime.now()).seconds)
            print("Deleting modlog messages 14 day or older")
            await asyncio.sleep(5) 
            await delete_messages(mgs)
            await ctx.send('Success!', delete_after=4)
            await asyncio.sleep(86400) # Wait 24 hours




def check_folder():
    if not os.path.exists('data/modlogset'):
        print('Creating data/modlogset folder...')
        os.makedirs('data/modlogset')


def check_file():
    f = 'data/modlogset/settings.json'
    if not fileIO(f, 'check'):
        print('Creating default settings.json...')
        fileIO(f, 'save', {})


def setup(bot):
    check_folder()
    check_file()
    q = ModLog(bot)
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.create_task(q.purge_modlog())
    bot.add_cog(q)
```

To loop the event under def `def setup(bot):` You can see

```
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.create_task(q.purge_modlog())
```

This is supposed to loop the event `(q.purge_modlog())` I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here. I have already tried the follow  `(q.purge_modlog(ctx, number))`

```
line 686, in setup
loop.create_task(q.purge_modlog(ctx, number))
NameError: name 'ctx' is not defined
```

If anyone could help me that would be great. To add this is a module.

Comment: is `purge_modlog` a `command`? Is it an attribute of a `ModLog` class?

Comment: No it's an event. Basically evey day it will check to purge messages within 14 days. I think there is a limit on Discord of 14 days.

I not sure on my method here but this is what I'm trying. But one based on message timestamp preferably would be better.

Comment: It's not an event, because it's not listed in the [Event reference](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/api.html#event-reference).  Remove all references to `ctx`.  No one is invoking a command, so there can't be an invocation context.  You need to add `self` as the first argument of all the methods of the cog, including events and commands.  I'm not sure how you're determining what channel to interact with, but you need to get that channel inside the coroutine (after the bot has started). Your function signature also requires a number, so you must pass one.

Comment: Maybe I'll have to re-code  as the event only wants 2 signatures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have corrected some mistakes here. Try to read through the discord.py documentation on [purging](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.purge_from) messages.

```
 class ModLog:
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot


async def on_ready(self):
    await self.bot.wait_until_ready()
    for server in self.bot.servers:
        channel = self.bot.get_channel("channel ID here")
        if channel:
            self.bot.loop.create_task(self.modlog_purge(channel))

async def modlog_purge(self, channel):
    while True:
        now = datetime.utcnow()
        two_weeks_ago = now - timedelta(days=14)
        await self.bot.purge_from(channel, before=two_weeks_ago)
        await asyncio.sleep(86400)

def setup(bot):
    q = ModLog(bot)
    bot.add_cog(q)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class ModLog:
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot
    async def on_ready(self):
        await self.bot.wait_until_ready()
        for guild in self.bot.guilds:
            channel = await self.get_channel(guild)
            if channel:
                self.bot.loop.create_task(self.modlog_purge(channel))
    async def get_channel(guild):
        # Whatever your logic for getting the Channel for a given guild is
    async def modlog_purge(self, channel):
        while True:
            now = datetime.utcnow()
            two_weeks_ago = now - timedelta(days=14)
            await channel.purge(before=two_weeks_ago)
            await asyncio.sleep(86400)

def setup(bot):
    q = ModLog(bot)
    bot.add_cog(q)
```

Here's how I would structure this (I'm not on a computer with `discord.py` at the moment, so there may be some errors).  We have an `on_ready` event that kicks off background tasks for each server that has a channel we want to maintain (this could instead loop through a list of channels, or something similar).

The actual purge is all taken care of by the [`TextChannel.purge`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/api.html#discord.TextChannel.purge) coroutine.  We just pass it a `datetime` object, and it deletes 100 messages from before that date (this is configurable).  It then sleeps for a day and repeats.